# GetModuleFileNameEx - Split output

Tags: c++, process

I trying to get process name from the process id, and I've use **GetModuleFileNameEx** and I write this function.

```
char* ProcessName(ULONG_PTR ProcessId)
{
    char szBuffer[MAX_PATH+1];
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, ProcessId);

    if(GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szBuffer, MAX_PATH) == 0)
        sprintf(szBuffer, "null");

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return szBuffer;
}
```

the output is Full-Path&Process-Name, and I want split it so I can get the process-name without Full-Path.

Is there any way to do this, or any other function can I use it to get process name from its process id?

Comment: Use _splitpath() ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf(v=vs.120).aspx ) to split full path to several parts.

Comment: Your code will fail unless the process name can be represented in the current codepage's subset of possible names, using the `WCHAR` variant of the function would be a reliable alternative.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Better advice is to avoid `char *` as most as possible in favor of `std::string`.

Comment: Don't you mean `std::wstring`, @vladon?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What I can do? (because when I try to add the code to new project its work fine **but** when I try to add it to my current source its fail)

Comment: Fail? In what way? And which code exactly?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `if(GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess, NULL, szBuffer, MAX_PATH) > 0)` its return **0** not more than **0**

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx: "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt GetLastError() return **(null)**

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you, I've use `GetProcessImageFileName` with `_fullpath` and `_splitpath_s` and its work fine. (Because `GetModuleFileNameEx` dosen't work with **32-bit app** in **64-bit systems**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you're returning a pointer to local memory and that is going to end in tears

```
char* ProcessName(ULONG_PTR ProcessId) {
    char szBuffer[MAX_PATH+1];
    ...
    return szBuffer;
}
```

Aside from that, you can use [_splitpath_s()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx) or the like to get the filename from your path, or the [PathFindFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function available on Windows platforms with the shell API

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "Psapi.h"
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

std::string ProcessName(DWORD ProcessId)
{
  std::string name;
  HANDLE Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, ProcessId);
  if (Handle) {
    TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, Buffer, MAX_PATH)) {
      name = std::string(PathFindFileName(Buffer));
    }
    else {
      // Now would be a good time to call GetLastError()
    }
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  }

  return name;
}

int main() {

  std::cout << ProcessName(GetCurrentProcessId());

  return 0;
}
```

You can test this code on a recent MSVC compiler [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)

Comment: `GetModuleFileNameEx` dosen't work with **32-bit app** in **64-bit systems**, so I've use `GetProcessImageFileName` with `_fullpath` and `_splitpath_s` and its work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PathFindFileName() to get a file name from path.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

this gets the file name only from the full path it searches the last characters for \ then moduleNameOnly is the last bit minus the \ i the "strrchr" is the char version of wcsrchr.

```
wchar_t* moduleNameOnly = wcsrchr(szModName, L'\\')+1;
```